# Swift Pass data from ViewController to one subview of TabBarController

Tags: swift, ios8

I have two `subview` in my `TabBarcontroller` and one of this, is connected with a one  `ViewController`
I would bring the `Label.text` from `Viewcontroller` to the first subview of my `TabBar` and I tryed with

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "returnView"{
        var destVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
        destVC.str = "\(helloLabel.text)"
    }
}
```

But don't go , how can I do ?